# Pressing back button does not place the vertical cursor where it was left after the page is rendered using ajax

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing the following action on a particular webpage:

1. Scrolling the web page a.aspx vertically and that I have scrolled down  at 30%.
2. Clicking on a hyperlink that gets me to another webpage b.aspx.
3. Now I press the back button and I get to the web page a.aspx and exactly it is placed at 30% down vertically. ie., to the place in the web where I had last scrolled.

Now consider the following scenario.

1. I am at a.aspx. Now Scrolling down is bringing more images programatically (asynchronously javascript) and is filling the page. Now my cursor is at 70%.
2. Clicking on a hyperlink that gets me to another webpage b.aspx.
3. Now I press the back button and I get to the web page a.aspx and I expect it the cursor to be placed at 70% but unfortunately it is not.

What is the problem? What should be done to take it to the item that was originally rendered from where I left?

Comment: Have a look at using localStorage, it allows you to save page state, so on return you'll be back where you started - http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to make use of [sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Something like (hypothetical):

```
    if Session["currentPage"] == "lastPageUserCameFrom"
    <%-- add #(id) section of page to url of
 Session["trailingPagePosition"] from other --%>
```

Assuming your page sections have an ID.
Or consider a JavaScript [history](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) api.